# Regex for XAML Formatting

Tags: regex, powershell, xaml

I'm attempting to build a PowerShell CmdLet that can parse and cleanly reformat a chunk of XAML or any other markup language.

So far, I've had to build an assortment of CmdLet's so that I can get the correct information to put into this thing (for indentation, counts, items, child items, etc, so forth...)

What I'm attempting to do is to collect ALL of the properties and values in a set of XAML/HTML, etc, and then once I have the lengths of all those variables, I can then start to chunk them out and properly format them so that they all output down a straight line. It may not make a super amount of sense as I describe it? So, here's an example.

```
<Window                                    xmlns = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
                                         xmlns:x = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'
                                           Title = 'Window Title'
                                          Height = '600'
                                       MinHeight = '600'
                                           Width = '800'
                                        MinWidth = '800'
                                     BorderBrush = 'Black'
                                      ResizeMode = 'CanResize'
                             HorizontalAlignment = 'Center'
                           WindowStartupLocation = 'CenterScreen'>
```

The reason I am attempting to build this, is so that I can programmatically save the instructions to a smaller footprint. So, *instead* of... having fluctuating numbers for each line and item and the end result looking like this...

```
<Window xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' 
xmlns:x = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' Title = 'Window Title' Height = '600' 
MinHeight = '600' Width = '800' MinWidth = '800' BorderBrush = 'Black' ResizeMode = 'CanResize'
HorizontalAlignment = 'Center' WindowStartupLocation = 'CenterScreen'>
```

...I then have a set of instructions that can vectorize the content of the XAML, so that it has a pattern and less randomness. Sure, the line count might get expanded quite a bit, but there's no need to be concerned with that if all it is doing is expanding into RAM. Which is the point of it...

At any rate, the code that I am having trouble with is essentially a way to preserve the spacing between the quoted objects. I feel like I'm beating my head against a wall trying to get this to work correctly when I know it's a matter of Regex ...

I've posted the code I'm talking about via this link.
https://github.com/secure-digits-plus-llc/FightingEntropy/blob/master/Format-XAML.ps1
Lines 43-147

It is a script block, and testing with it requires a Xaml Here String.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I'm not much of a Regex fan, I understand some basics to it but I'm not that great with it yet.

-MC

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer I was looking for.

Not the most eloquent way to solve the issue I was having, but it works.

"(?<=\').+?(?=\')"

When the lines are split, and you want to preserve the spacing within the quotes, then you need something like this.

I was attempting to iterate through a do loop until the array/string contained (2) single quotes, but what was happening was... 'oh. I thought you wanted to match 'adbhjikvgrfe' with '21345rfs'.

No regex. Wasn't looking to match that. *sigh*.

Then it was taking the spacing out between the quotes.
*sigh*

I gotta say... anyone who truly writes good programming...? Well, I tip my hat off to you good sir/ma'am... because... it's a frustrating job. For certain.